# java method find max price

Tags: java, arrays, methods

My `findmaxprice` method returns the index of the first Car in the array with the maximum price. If it is not found, -1 is returned.

As far as I know, `return` will stop the for loop.  Any advice on how to avoid it while keep the loop search for max price?

```java
public int findmaxprice() {
    double max =0;
    for(int i =0; i < nCars; i++) {
        if(max <= Cars[i].getPrice()) {
            max = Cars[i].getPrice();
            return i; //the problem is here
        }   
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: yep, return will stop the loop and return the current value of i.  so, don't `return` i inside the loop, wait until you've checked all the values in nCars, and *then* return it

Comment: Create another var `int found_index = -1` Then set `found_index = i;` when max found. Then `return found_index;`

Comment: Lots to do on this method.The method name should be changed. Either return the max price value or change the method name to something like `findMaxPriceIndex()`. Second please use camel casing for example `findMaxPrice()`

Comment: i took this question from prev exam so i didnt change the name of the method. also, im new to stackoverflow so i dont know how to "camel" a method. thanks anyway

Comment: All camel case means is first word is lowercase, then the first letter of each sub subsequent word is capital. likeThis. camelCase. It's not necessary but it helps a lot when someone reads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost answered yourself - just don't return in the for loop.

```
public int findmaxprice() {
  double max =0;
  int maxIndex = -1;

  for( int i =0; i < nCars; i++) {
    if(max <= Cars[i].getPrice()) {
      max = Cars[i].getPrice();
      maxIndex = i;
    }   
  }

  return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: and maybe consider renaming your method to `getIndexOfMaxPrice()` or something

Answer (score 0):

Move the return statement outside of the loop

```
findmaxprice method: returns the index of the first Car in the array with the maximum price. If it is not found, -1 is returned. as far as i know, return will stop the for loop , any advice on how to avoid it while keep the loop search for max price ?

public int findmaxprice() {
    double max =0;
    for( int i =0; i < nCars; i++) {
        if(max <= Cars[i].getPrice()) {
            max = Cars[i].getPrice();

    }   
    }
    if(max != 0){
        return max;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below method will fix your issue. Also, it gives you ability to specify a minimum price above which the car price will be considered for max calculation. You can keep this 0 in function call like `findMaxPrice(0)`if no such boundation needed.

```
public int findMaxPrice(int min) {
    double max = min;
    int maxPriceCarIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nCars; i++) {
        if (max <= Cars[i].getPrice()) {
            max = Cars[i].getPrice();
            maxPriceCarIndex = i; //reassign the index here
        }
    }
    return maxPriceCarIndex;
  }
```

Comment: thanks, although there is no parameter but it solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just need the "most expensive" car and not the index of the car, then you could consider using streams

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().testGetMostExpensiveCar();
    }

    private void testGetMostExpensiveCar() {
        // test null array
        Car[] cars = null;
        Car mostExpensive = getMostExpensiveCar(cars);
        System.out.println(mostExpensive); // prints null

        // test empty array
        cars = new Car[10];
        mostExpensive = getMostExpensiveCar(cars);
        System.out.println(mostExpensive); // prints null

        //test array with cars
        cars[0] = new Car(10.0);
        cars[5] = new Car(20.0);
        cars[8] = new Car(30.0);
        cars[8] = new Car(30.0);
        mostExpensive = getMostExpensiveCar(cars);
        System.out.println(mostExpensive);// prints Car [price=30.0]
    }

    /**
     * @param cars
     * @return the most Expensive car, null if the array is empty or no car is in
     *         the array
     */
    public Car getMostExpensiveCar(Car[] cars) {
        if (cars == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Arrays.stream(cars) // creates a Stream<Car> (take a look at e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull) // because there can be "null" values in the array
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Car::getPrice)) // compares the car by price asc
                .orElse(null); // return null if no element is found
    }

    private class Car {
        private double price;

        public Car(double price) {
            super();
            this.price = price;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Car [price=" + price + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe he does, but he *probably* just want's the index, because that's what he asked for in his question - so this answers a question that doesn't really exist.